# Why getBoundingClientRect returns null when pointing to a negative coordinate position in svg?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

The trick part might be the `viewBox="-50 0 150 100"`. But I really need to get the negative coordinates.

Please take a look at the demo below:

```js
$('svg').click(function(e){
  const { farthestViewportElement: svgRoot } = e.target;
  const dim = svgRoot.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = e.clientX - dim.left;
  const y = e.clientY - dim.top;
  $('#cord-track').val(`x: ${x}, y: ${y}`);
})
```

```css
svg {border:1px dashed blue}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>When you click mouse in the red rect, it works perfectly</p>
<p>When you click mouse in the left blank zone, it throws an error, so that I can't trace my x and y values. How do I fix it?</p>
<svg width="100px" id="test" viewBox="-50 0 150 100">
<rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="red">
</svg>
<input id="cord-track" />
```

Comment: This happens because there is no event target where you are clicking. Try drawing a `<rect x="-50" y="0" width="150" height="100" fill="none" pointer-events="all "/>` behind the red one. Also do not forget closing the tag  `/>`

Comment: Oh, I see. If there's no element there, the `<svg>` won't be "clicked" ....

Answer (score 0):

https://www.google.com/search?q=FarthestViewportElement

The documentation for `FarthestViewportElement` says:

> The farthest ancestor ‘svg’ element.
> **Null if the current element is the outermost svg element**

Thus when you click the `<svg>` **itself**, you get a `null` value

So instead, get that `<svg>` with `e.target.closest("svg")`

Note: this will ofcourse fail when you have `<svg>` **inside** `<svg>`;
use a full size `<rect>` as first element then for a *catch all*

```js
MYSVG.onclick = e => {
  let svg = e.target.closest("svg");
  let path = e.composedPath().map(el => el.nodeName ).join(",");
  console.log("CLICKED:",e.target.nodeName,"IN:",svg.id,"CLICK PATH:",path);
}
```

```css
svg {
  width:180px;
  border: 1px dashed blue
}
```

```html
<svg id="MYSVG" viewBox="-50 0 150 100">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```